# Greasemonkey Javascript, Speed up xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, performance, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, greasemonkey

I want to know the methods to speed up an XHR (xmlHhttpRequest) GET.

I have an application that keeps sending an GM_xmlHttpRequest every X seconds.
The essential idea is, the faster I get the a response that satisfy a condition, faster I can take an action.
What I've done so far, is to set a timeout, like 2000ms, and track the number of timeouts and success.
Depending on these numbers I increase or decrease the X value.
Example:

> sent 10 requests, timeout_count=8, success_count=2.
>   if (timeout_count==8) xSeconds=xSeconds+100;
>   if (timeout_success==10) xSeconds=xSeconds-10;

Something like this.
Of course, this isn't a performance, and it's only a way I found to improve the speed of the calls depending on the internet speed factor.

What I need to know is...

Is there another methods to increase the speed of the requests of a "keep-sending" XHR application?

Methods like setting headers with specific values, or maybe some API, or maybe some programming approach? Something/Someway that make the requests lighter...

Thank you very much.

EDIT: As the user Bergi demanded, I'm adding this explanation:
somesite.com is a feed site, like... if I run a regExp to find a certain string in the response, I will send-me an e-mail. Something like this.

My code is something like this:

```
var count_success = 0;
var count_timeout = 0;
var requestTime = 1000;
var httpRequest = function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        httpRequest();
        httpRequest_get();
    },requestTime);
}

var httpRequest_get = function() {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://www.somesite.com/",
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
            "Accept": "text/xml",
        },
        timeout: 2000,
        ontimeout: function() {
            timeout_count++;
            count_timeout++;
            if(count_timeout==5) {
                requestTime=requestTime+100;
                count_timeout=0;
            }
        },
        onload: function(response) {
            // do something with the response
            count_success++;
            if(count_success==5) {
                requestTime=requestTime-50;
                count_success=0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Answer to the comment made by the user Bergi:**

It's not under my control. It's a feed site, as I mentioned. I want to monitor the offers showed by this feed, each offer has a price, and when an item under a certain price is matched, I send-me an e-mail. Then seeing this e-mail poping out in my phone, I can decide either to buy it or not.

There is doc to their API, as far as it goes, I only have the code I can study under his page. I started with the making requests for the feed site, just www.somesite.com, but the requests were tooking too much, the length of the string was greater than 80k. Then, I monitored their feed to see what their site are doing to update the feed, then I found the XHR they do every X time, I used to replicate this request, then the string went down to 10k or less sometimes.

Well, you got the idea, The faster I do it, the better. Matter of fact, I want to do it under 300ms. I already achieved the avg of 800ms. Also, you must be questioning yourself, why so fast? what's the matter between 800ms and 300ms? The answer is, there is also another ppl scripting the same thing and their scripts are faster than mine. I'm looking for somehow reduce the size of the request, maybe changing the headers, but I'm not getting much success on it. The internet factor is also important, I know this for sure, but I can't afford it at the moment. I just hope there are ways of optimizing it without depending only of the connection speed factor. Thanks.

Comment: We would need to know more about the particular [type of] API you're contacting. "somesite.com" doesn't help much.

Comment: It's a feed site, like... if I run a regExp to find a certain string in the response, I will send-me an e-mail. Something like this.

Comment: I'd say that a) this better be done at a server (with good internet connection) instead of a greasemonkey script b) in that pull-based approach, the response time shouldn't matter anyway. If you *need* high-performance (which is hardly the case if the action is just an email) then you should get a push-based API access to the queried service.

Comment: This part of pull-based/push-based is a little bit complicated to me, but I did some research. You mean, the programming approach I'm using is called PULL-BASED, and you recommend-me to use an PUSH-BASED API instead. You should add a response explaining your thoughts about PULL/PUSH based approachs, and some examples of API if you know. Thanks.

Comment: That depends completely on what service your www.somesite.com does offer. Is it under your control? If not, you might link the API docs for it.

Comment: Answered at the end of the topic. I hope it helps.

Comment: If you first had to check your email, read about the offer and then go to buy it then a half second should not really matter? Or is a buying bot instead of sending emails? Also, please include a link to the docs of that page if you say there are some.

Comment: First I will try to send-me an e-mail, then, I will check if it's possible to do it automatically, besides I don't know if it's legal, I mean, within the ToS. There's no documentation. Thanks.